# difference between using php and SQLite class

Tags: android, database

what is the difference between using SQLite class implementing SQLiteOpenHelper 
AND 
using php to connect my database to android project

Comment: Do you have some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQLite you use a local database of Android Device, and with PHP... Do you mean a database on your server?

Android can't execute PHP, you should connect to server with run php connection to database a return the info to Android.